# Associate facebook API with Android

Tags: android, facebook, api

I'm having trouble to work with facebook API within my android app.

I have a login button on my app. And I wish that the user clicks the login button and associate with a facebook account. However, I'd like to do it without the facebook predefined design.

I'm having a big trouble understanding the facebook API, I would love some help.

All documentation I find on the net is not that clear to me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I used this one in my project [link](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook).

It's very simple and useful.

Example to get profile you need to write:

```
mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(new OnProfileRequestAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Profile profile)
    {
        String id = profile.getId();
        String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
        String birthday = profile.getBirthday();
        String email = profile.getEmail();
        String bio = profile.getBio();
        // ... and many more properties of profile ...
    }
});
```

Good luck!